# Progressbar in Activity with asyncTask Download in External .class-File

Tags: android, android-activity, download, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have a progessbar in an activity but the Async is in an external .class-File
How do i refer to that progessbar in the async task?

i use a slightly changed version of the AsyncTask from
[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: How about providing a reference to the progressBar in the constructor of AsyncTask?

Comment: that did not work, or i did something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a setter method in the asyncTask class like this:

```
public class MyTask extends asyncTask .... {
     private ProgressBar bar;
     public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar bar){
              this.bar = bar;
        }
 }
```

then from the activity when creating a new asyncTask just set the progress bar. something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  private ProgressBar bar;
  private myTask task;


 void createTask(){
   myTask = new MyTask(....);
   myTask.setProgressBar(bar);
   }
}
```